# Angular Routing not as expected for lazyload modules. Working for manually entering url but from navigation menu always redirecting to default route

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, url-routing, submenu

I have nested lazy load modules, when I navigate through the sub-menu(children) nested modules always redirect to default route, but while entering URL manually it is working fine.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3ik1q2

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
You have to play with CSS logic is here

```
<div id="container">
    <ul class="navigation">
        <li *ngFor="let nav of navs"  routerLinkActive="active">
            <span *ngIf="nav.sub_navs">{{ nav.title }}</span>
            <span [routerLink]="['', nav.link]" *ngIf="!nav.sub_navs">{{ nav.title }}</span>
            <span *ngIf="nav.sub_navs" style="margin-left: 30px;font-size: 1.5rem">&#8250;</span>
            <ul *ngIf="nav.sub_navs" class="sub_nav">
                <li *ngFor="let sub_nav of nav.sub_navs" [routerLink]="['', nav.link, sub_nav.link]" routerLinkActive="active">
                    {{ sub_nav.title }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="main-section">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```